# CKEditor 4 config - relative paths

Tags: ckeditor

I have been using CKE 4.3.4 for a while (in conjunction with ASP.NET 4.0) and it is generally working fine. But I am having great trouble in configuring features in config.js where I need to specify a path - for example, for a custom stylesheet file (config.stylesSet) or a custom image browser (config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl). I have only been able to get this to work by specifying an absolute url - e.g. //ckeditor/customstyles.js. Although this works, I am unhappy having to do so as it makes running my applications in different environments difficult and is also an issue when testing using IIS Express which does not provide a root name. I have seen suggestions elsewhere that I need to set a BASEHREF global variable, but I can't see why I shouldn't be able to do this within config.js itself rather than in some external script tag or whatever. I feel sure that I used to be able to do something similar with FCKEditor or earlier versions of CKEditor, so would be grateful if anyone could remind me of the correct syntax.

Jon

Comment: When I wrote the above post, the 'absolute' url had [websiterootname] between tag-like braces between the double slash - but this got deleted

Comment: In case it helps anyone, the following works for urls like filebrowserImageBrowseUrl:

CKEDITOR.basepath + 'browser/ImageBrowser.aspx'

But for stylesSet, I had to move my custom styles to a subfolder of the CKE installation folder and use:

'{name}:styles/customstyles.js'

Comment: If you want to set paths in your config, eg, if you are specifying alternative css files, use CKEDITOR.getUrl( 'contents.css' ); or multiple with multiple files: [CKEDITOR.getUrl( 'contents.css' ), CKEDITOR.getUrl( 'myContents.css' )];